# How to check two php arrays have one equal value

Tags: php, arrays

I have very very simple question and i not found good one in stack.

we have to array like :

```
array("1","2","3","4");
```

and

```
array("a","b","1","c");
```

The second array, have one value of the first one , I want to have a function that checks two array and return True , if , there is one or more than one equal value in two arrays.

How can i do it ?

Like :

```
if(have_equal($array1,$array2)) {
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try like this:

```
if(array_intersect($array1, $array2))
{
   return true;
}
else
{  
   return false;
}
```

Check for **[array_intersect](https://www.php.net/array_intersect)**

> array_intersect() returns an array containing all the values of array1
> that are present in all the arguments. Note that keys are preserved.

Answer (score 1):

you just have to use the array_intersect() fct, read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
if(array_intersect($array1, $array2)){}
```

Comment: how to return true or false with this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
function have_equal(array $arr1, array $arr2){
   return count(array_intersect($arr1, $arr2)) > 0;
}
```